# USB Serial driver in Linux and device name

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, device-driver

My device is a USB serial device. When I plug in, the cdc_acm.ko driver detects it and a node is created under /dev/ with the device name as ttyACM0. When I do a soft reset, the device appears with the name ttyACM1. Where can I get the information regarding the device name [under /proc/ or /etc]. Currently I am relying on dmesg to detect the device name. Once I intend to automate it, I would like to know where I can get the device name information.

Answer (score 0):

use **/proc/devices** for reading major number and device name information.

a sample output is attached.

```
  useer@useer-VirtualBox:~$ cat /proc/devices

  Character devices:

  1 mem
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  5 ttyprintk
  6 lp
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
```

Left side integers are major number of the corresponding devices.

Comment: The device ttyACM0 is not listed in /proc/devices at all. I just get the details of the device when I enter dmesg command. Is there some other way to figure this out?

Comment: Are you getting ttyACM in /proc/devices ??? ttyACM1, ttyACM0 are device instances, where as ttyACM is driver.

Comment: Yes I can see ttyACM listed in /proc/devices. But I need the device instance majorly. Do you have any idea of how to find that out?